# Does firebase logged in users are considered as concurrent users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app where i'm using firebase as a database(a free plan i.e 100 concurrent users at a time). Let say user comes to my app, register and gets logged in and is not supposed to log out of the app.

1. The confusion for me is that does that logged in user be counted as
   a concurrent user on firebase? Even if the user closes the
   app(without logging out), is this be still counted as concurrent? Or
   else firebase will itself remove that particular user from the row?
2. Secondly when should i use goOffline? I am not sure about what it
   actually does.

I have already gone through the present look a like SO questions but they didn't cleared my confusion. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "concurrent user" is a user who has your app open and is maintaining a socket connection to the database.  This connection will be broken when the app is no longer working.  So, users who are not actively using your app with an open connection do not count as a "concurrent user".

Use goOffline when you want the database connection to be closed until you call goOnline, or the app is killed and the user launches it again.  A vast majority of apps don't have a use for this.

Comment: And how much time does it take to go back online?

Comment: As long as it takes for the SDK to establish the socket.  No way to predict how long that will take.